# Has API limit to getting file?

Tags: php, convertapi

I had problem, when i tried send the big PDF file (42 mb). Has API limit to getting file?
My code:

```
$filename_pdf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/test_pdf_2.pdf';

$fh_res = fopen($filename_pdf, 'r');

$login = '******';
$password = '*********';
$url = 'http://do.convertapi.com/Pdf2Image';

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile($filename_pdf, 'application/pdf', 'test_pdf_2.pdf');
$data = array(
    'File' => $cfile,
    'OutputFormat' => 'jpg',
    'ApiKey' => '******',
    'StoreFile' => 1,
    'Timeout'=>'1200'
);

$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filename_pdf));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

My code working with small files. Has API limit to getting file?

Comment: What is the value of `$return`? What is the max file size the API accept?

Answer (score 2):

There are some limitations. In your php.ini file you can find the values. Directly concerned are:

1. post_max_size
2. upload_max_filesize
3. max_file_uploads
4. max_input_time

You can inspect the values with `phpinfo()` and simply change them. Here a how to change your configuration:
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

This whole thing for sure only applies to your server. You can't check the settings of another server, so its totally possible that the endpoint you're calling will block big files.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My server has this configurations:

```post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time = 60 ```

Comment: @Samir may the `max_input_time` is too short, 1 minute for 42mb is quite fast I think. May you can try to increase it and test it again. But not sure if this will help.

Comment: This is partially correct. As the file itself is already in the server (as specified in codes in the questions), `upload_max_filesize` and `max_file_uploads` are not really related. As OP is using cURL to transfer the file to target API, the timeout value of cURL has to be changed, or the file transfer will time out. Also, does the target API support uploading files in chunks? Uploading huge file in one shot doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @Twinfriends I increased the limit.   Now max_execution_time = 360

Answer (score 0):

> You can check in your `php.ini` files for below lines.

- upload_max_filesize = 2M
- post_max_size = 2M
- max_execution_time
- file_uploads
- max_input_time
- memory_limit

**upload_max_filesize :** Maximum allowed size for uploaded files

**post_max_size :** Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept

**max_execution_time :** Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds

**file_uploads :** Whether to allow HTTP file uploads

**max_input_time :** Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data

**memory_limit :** Maximum amount of memory a script may consume

> Set the desired values for above lines. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мой сервер имеет следующие конфигурации:  `Upload_max_filesize = 100M post_max_size = 100M max_execution_time = 360 file_uploads = on max_input_time = 360 memory_limit = 256M`

Comment: After saving this configuration, You must restart your Server. @Samir

Comment: I restarted. No working. I think "http://do.convertapi.com/Pdf2Image" has limit to get a file.

Comment: Try `upload_max_filesize` instead of `Upload_max_filesize` @Samir

Comment: You should debug `phpinfo();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php , Then you will see, what is the actual configuration in your server. @Samir

Comment: In my configuration is "upload_max_filesize". All correct.